# How to disable all default hotkeys and behaviors

Tags: javascript, html

Is there an easy way to disable all the default hotkeys and key actions for a HTML5 game?

I've gone through many steps disabling one thing after another, and the code keeps piling up. I just accidentally closed the tab with ctrl+w because I added that as a in-game action, and I'm really getting tired of this. I'd like to get some easy way to disable everything except what I specifically set to do something, if at all possible.

I also have a problem with shift+right click activating the right click menu (normal right click menu is disabled), and I don't know how to disable it.

I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Did you try a catch-all `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: ...no. I've been using it where ever I needed. I just added it to the top of my keyboard event and that did it. It was too simple lol, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set it up as a catch-all in your event handler. (Expanding from comment.)

For example, instead of:

```
window.onclick = function(e){
    if (e.which == 'w'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do your stuff
    } else if (e.which == 's'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do your stuff
    }
};
```

You might do:

```
window.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which == 'w'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        // do your stuff
    } else if (e.which == 's'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        // do your stuff
    }
};
```